# Struts2 escaping select values

Tags: select, struts2, escaping, space

I have text in a option (using a select tag) that has multiple spaces.  These spaces are then converted into one space.  I then tried to escape the spaces with `&nbsp;` but it then converts it to:

&nbsp;

which is not what I want.  Is there anyway to disable escaping in Strut2 or have it always escape spaces for me for select tags?  There is a way to turn off escapes for property tags but nothing for select, that I can see.

Answer (score -1):

Try with attributes escape=false or escapeAmp=false

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/select.html clearly shows that escape and escapeAmp are not legal for the select tag